# Finding the non leaves in a Binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying to create a binary tree and try to count the non leaves in Java. How can I found the numbers of non leaves? Any suggestions please?
here is a part of my code:

```
      public int no_leaves() 
        { BTNode<Integer> n = root; 
         int count=0; 
        while(n!=null ) 
        { 
        if((n.right==null)&& (n.left==null)) 
        {continue; 

        } 
        else
        { 
          count++; 
        } 
        } 
       System.out.println(count); 
      return count; 
      }
```

Comment: Do some kind of (recursive) tree walk and count just those nodes, which have children (which are the "non-leaves").

Comment: Do any type of tree traversal(post,pre,in). keep a Static counter. Increment it if either left or right node of given node exists.

Comment: Do you know how to search through all the node? Do you know how to check if a node is a left node or not? What have you tried and what are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @AniketThakur A static counter wouldn't be very thread safe. You can just return the number of nodes found.

Comment: No i am just creating a binary tree in java. I know i have to use recursive function but i dont know how...

Comment: Google "Java binary tree traversal" and that should send you well on your way.

Answer (score 2):

A tree consists of node-objects. In each node object you hold information about the children.
`Node leftChild;` and   `Node rightChild;`. If any of those in not null, you have an inner node.

Edit:
There are three posibilities to traverse a binary tree. preorder, inorder an postorder.

Preorder: Do something with your Node, then check the left subtree (call same method with leftChild), then check the right subtree.

Inorder: For each node (recursivly), start with the LeftChild then do something with the node and then contiue with the rightChild.

Postorder: For each node(recursivly), start with the leftChild, then go to the right side and in the end do something with your node.

For example in preorder traversal:

```
    public int countLeaves(Node node) {
      if(node.left == null && node.right == null) {
       //this is a leaveNode; no more method calls to countLeaves
      } else {
         // this is not a leaveNode, check subtrees.
         // call countLeaves() with the children of node
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's the name of the method I wrote. Calling it from within that same method is called recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a full walk of the tree (depth-first recursive walk is probably the easiest to implement) and at every node check to see if it has any children. 
A node with at least one child counts as a non-leaf.

Comment: and how you can find the clidren in binary tree using java?